# How to show the toolbar only in certain modes?

Tags: emacs, toolbar

Is it possible to toolbar only when certain modes are used for the current buffer?
What I am aiming at is have the toolbar only active when gdb-gud or newsticker are running,
so that a quick interaction with it is possible. As soon as e.g. newsticker is closed, the toolbar-mode should be disabled.
Is there a general way to achieve this behavior, or do I have to write something myself?

Comment: It's possible to activate the toolbar only for a certain frame: `(set-frame-parameter nil 'tool-bar-lines 1)`  Not sure if there's an easy way to make it per mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tool-bar-mode` is a global mode. You can of course turn it on or off on a mode hook, but it affects all buffers in all frames.

As @legoscia mentioned, you can make the tool bar *frame*-specific.  `tool-bar-here-mode` makes this easier (togglable). It is in library [`tool-bar+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/tool-bar%2b.el)

I don't think you can easily limit use of the tool bar to a particular mode.

However, you can make showing the tool bar be **on-demand** when you click `Buttons` in the menu bar.  This saves screen real estate: Show the tool bar temporarily, for the space of a single use.

This is available with `tool-bar-popup-mode`, which is also in library [`tool-bar+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/tool-bar%2b.el).

[*Screenshots and description*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToolBar#toc3).